# Multi row column in 960 grid system

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I need to make a page which makes use of the 960 grid system which has a multi-row column. What I mean is I have three columns in a 16 column separated into 3-10-3 but on the last column, I need to make several divs for news feed, ads and also a "follow us on..." box which will all be aligned vertically. Refer to the picture for a visual pov.

[image: Site idea]

Is there a way to this on 960gs? It seems like I can just pile divs of equal width in the column but I don't know. Help please

Comment: Have you tried to code this page?

Comment: Provide what you've tried as code, or perhaps create a visual mark-up demo [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I tried:

`<div class="grid_3" style="background-color: yellow">Right side`  
`<div class="grid_3" style="background-color: blue"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div>`  
`<div class="grid_3" style="background-color: red"><p>Etiam accumsan orci et metus accumsan ac euismod quam molestie.</p></div>`  
`<div class="grid_3" style="background-color: cyan"><p>Morbi at tortor ultricies neque vestibulum interdum ut et tortor.</p></div>`  
`</div>`  

But the divs floated out of the column slightly. Could be a margin or padding preset problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, turns out instead of using more divs with 'grid_x' classes within a grid column, you can just use normal divs with no classes and it will automatically align to the parent div.